# Are the Kree the good guys?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, captain-marvel-2019

In the new Captain Marvel trailer, when asked by Nick Fury about Krees, Carol Danvers answers that they are a race of **'noble warrior heroes'.**
But in Guardians of the Galaxy, Ronan, who was a Kree, was without a doubt, a bad guy. Nova Corps seem good, and the Krees do not like them at all.
So are the Krees actually bad? Or was Ronan just one single bad guy from a group of overall good people?

Comment: Do you mean in general (comics etc), or for the upcoming _Captain Marvel_ movie?

Comment: http://marvelcinematicuniverse.wikia.com/wiki/Kree

Comment: @Jenayah In general, but within the MCU, counting movies and TV shows, not comics (they are too wierd).

Comment: @Valorum I have not watched Inhumans, so all I can gather form the page is that these guys just keep fighting all other super powerful empires, doing illegal experiments on other races along the way, unless forced to sign peace treaty or something, and then some even don't care about that too. I feel they are the guys just always wanting war, like some destruction knack they need to satisfy by any means. Is it so?

Comment: If all you knew about Germany, for instance, was Josef Mengele's experiments, WWII. and Kaiser Wilhelm, or all you knew about the US was the Cold War, the Tuskagee syphilis experiments, and so forth, they might look a lot like the Kree. By the nature of the situations in the MCU, we've seen a selection of the nastiest or most warlike individuals of that society, and the most imperialist factions.

Comment: @Adamant yeah I get it...but still you need to super war like for the most part to keep fighting a war for (as mentioned on the page) "hundreds of decades". Like seriously? This is like thousands of years. And with the level of technology these people have, you can imagine the casualties and destruction. And they still want to keep fighting? Which sane person does that?

Comment: @Prakhar Peace and prosperity leads to stagnation and eventually death for an empire, at least if you lose a war you died strong.  WWII era japan had some factions that wanted to continue fighting even after the bombs.

Comment: @Revenant Peace, prosperity, stagnation, death? I don't know how could you use all these words in one single sentence.

Comment: @PrakharMishra Why are you so racist against Kree though

Comment: Krees aren't described as really good nice and sweet people in Agents of Shield either... once again, maybe it's only some of them... but for sure, Ronan is not the only bad one

Comment: @Adamant that should be an answer

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There's a few things to consider here...

**Ronan was a fanatic**

In fact, it's the first thing he says in *Guardians of the Galaxy*:

> Ronan: They call me "terrorist," "radical," "zealot," because I obey the ancient laws of my people, the Kree, and punish those who do not. Because I do not forgive your people for taking the life of my father, and his father, and his father before him. A thousand years of war between us will not be forgotten!

Ronan is critical of the Kree government because, in his mind, they have strayed from the defining principles of being Kree by declaring peace with Xandar.  He is, by his own account, not representative of the Kree people or the Kree Empire as a whole.

**Empires don't see themselves as the bad guys**

I'm American, and my country's portrayal of its own history illustrates this probably as well as any.  In our history books, our war of independence from the British Empire is told as the story of an underdog achieving a great victory against the tyranny and oppression of a king.  The actual history is considerably more convoluted than that and I'm sure the British tell it a little differently.

However, when America began expanding its influence in the 19th and 20th centuries, we aren't the oppressors but liberators promoting "freedom" and "democracy" (as long as it's our version of freedom and democracy).  Again, the history is considerably less black and white than all that, but it illustrates the point - the concept of an "empire" is a lot easier to sell to your citizens if you paint yourselves as the good guys.  So when Carol Danvers says the Kree are a race of noble warriors, that's likely how the Kree populace sees itself overall.  However, the Xandarians would probably describe them differently.

Comment: "and I'm sure the British tell it a little differently."  I don't know a lot about British history, but I do know you're right about that; for starters, what we Americans call the Revolutionary War they call the American Rebellion.

Comment: @PlutoThePlanet No we mostly commonly call it the Amercian War of Independence, but in principle we do tell history differently. I could not understand why the Mel Gibson movie called The Patriot" dwelt so much on the actions of a traitor,

Comment: @PlutoThePlanet: actually, we call it “The Noble Failure”, and wonder when you'll realise what a whoopsie the whole affair has been and start paying your taxes again.

Comment: "a great victory against the tyranny and oppression of a king" - which is *hilarious*, given that the whole thing started with the Americans deciding that the King had given *too much* power to Parliament - who were raising taxes, et cetera - and felt he should be reigning them in and enforcing **his** rule over the colonies, with the British Parliament being relegated to only ruling Great Britain.  It was only *after* the war had been going on for a while that they moved from "for the crown, against the parliament" to a full "leave the empire" position.

Answer (score 7):

Warning: This answer may contain spoilers for Captain Marvel, so I'll be using spoiler tags. It also leans on information from how some characters are in the comics, and that can sometimes change from comics to movies.

> Thanks to Funko Pops, it looks like we know that Jude Law will be playing a character known as Yon-Rogg [see Funko Pop lineup](https://www.reddit.com/r/marvelstudios/comments/a1orks/first_look_at_captain_marvel_funko_pops_leaked/). In the comics, Yon-Rogg is a villain to the original Captain Marvel. He's also responsible for the explosion of the Psyche-Magnetron, which is what gives Carol her powers.

We see in the trailer for Captain Marvel that she's part of an elite team called Star Force. Its members include (besides Carol and Jude Law's character, which I noted above) Ronan, Korath, Att-Lass, Bron-Char, and Minn-Erva, which in the comics are all villains.

> So it's likely that, yes, the real villains in Captain Marvel will likely end up being the Kree, seeing as Carol seems to have had her mind wiped and is serving on a team comprised only of Kree villains.

It should also be noted that the Skrulls aren't exactly boy scouts, and it's likely that Carol is wrapped up in a fight between two bad sides, with one side using her for her powers.