# Why are the Captain Marvel trailers portraying the Kree as heroic?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, captain-marvel-2019

Here's what we know about the Kree so far in the MCU:

From *Guardians of the Galaxy*, we've got Ronan, a warrior who's the villain because he upholds the ancient traditions of his people, and sees their recent peace treaty with Xandar as a betrayal of these principles and traditions.  While he never specifically enumerates what these traditions are, his actions in pursuit of upholding them show his intentions to be genocidal in nature, and the Kree empire, despite their peace treaty, specifically refuses to do anything to stop him, nor even to offer a token official condemnation of his actions.

From *Agents of SHIELD*, we see that the Kree have a long history of meddling in human development, creating the Inhumans to be used as super-powered soldier slaves.  Every time we've seen them they are practically universally portrayed as ruthless and cruel with no regard for the rights or well-being of others.  (Season 5 in particular focuses heavily on their status as horrific monsters!)

But now we're getting trailers for *Captain Marvel*, in which she describes the Kree as noble, valiant protectors of the cosmos.  This is set in the 90s, almost certainly before the peace treaty that ended their brutal, (likely) genocidal war against the Xandarians, which was a new thing 20 years later.

How are we to reconcile these two exceptionally opposed takes on the Kree and the morality of their culture?

Comment: This will most likely be explained in the movie.  Maybe Carol has only ever been fed pro-Kree propaganda, or maybe our existing examples are bad ones.

Comment: Thanos killed half the universe. His race were a bunch of Peaceniks

Comment: Would the downvoters care to comment?

Comment: Voted to close as this (IMO) falls under the future works policy.

Comment: Didn't we already have a version of this question?

Comment: I'll reiterate what I said on that question: what we've seen of the Kree empire is an extremist terrorist (Guardians of the Galaxy), some brutal occupiers associated with one political dynasty (Agents of Shield) and experiments on "lesser" beings in the recent past. This isn't just a description of the Kree Empire; it would work as a description of Japan, the United States, Germany, Britain. So are these people noble warriors, evil invaders, or neither?

Comment: VTRO now the film has been released. This can get a proper answer.

Comment: Adamant Maybe this is the question that you were thinking of: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/200266/are-the-kree-the-good-guys

Answer (score 12):

Carol says that the Kree are heroic, and we see a few flashbacks from her perspective of them portrayed positively. However, there is no indication that she is *correct*. The same trailer shows quite clearly that her memories have been significantly tampered with, and that discovering more about her past will be an important plot point. It seems quite likely that her view of the Kree will be challenged over the course of the movie.

Comment: Besides, the MCU has a history of misleading trailers.

Comment: True. It would be a nice plot "twist".

Comment: Having seen the film, and without revealing spoilers, I can say that this answer is on the right track.

Answer (score 0):

Now that *Captain Marvel* is out, we can assume that the trailers were misleading, and that the Kree are in fact the bad guys in the movie.

Comment: The _why_ is the main question here which you've answered with "the trailers were misleading" but you might want to expand on why they were misleading a bit more.

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot The main question is How and not Why, and based on the question, the Kree are the good guys in the movie, wich is not true, so from that perspective, the question isn't even valid, I think the OP was wondering how come the Kree are the good guys in the movie even if they are the bad guys in the  MCU(Ronan) and Agents of SHIELD.